# Unable to remove directory "Example" Access to the path "Example" is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am trying to build my MVC project and I am getting this error, can anyone advise on how to fix it? The code above the error is where it takes me to when I double click on the error.
[Error on VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq6mW.png)

Comment: Can you delete those directories from Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

For development - start you Visual Studio as Administrator.
For production - IIS user should be granted with an access to the space, where you hold your "Example" folder.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of reasons, but when I personally hit that issue, it's because the `IIS Express` has them "locked". So *one* way to resolve is to stop running the IIS Express process.

IIS Express process starts/runs when you "Start without Debugging" <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or "Start Debugging" <kbd>F5</kbd>

- if you're debugging, just stop debugging
- otherwise, right click on the IIS Express Icon  [image: IIS Express Icon in Windows Taskbar]
  at the bottom right of Windows Taskbar and exit/stop

Hth